# Should there be one or multiple XXXRepository instances in my system, with DDD?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

There's something that has been bothering from my DDD readings. From what I've seen, it seems as if there is only repository instance for each given aggregate root type in my system.

Consider, for instance, the following imaginary situation as an abstraction of a deeper domain model:

[image]

When coding in a "standard-style" I'd consider that each `Owner` in my system would have its own collection of cars, so there would be an equal number of `Car` collections (should I call it Repositories?) as there are `Owner`s. But, as stated previously, it seems as if in DDD I should only have *one* `CarRepository` in the whole system (I've seen examples in which they are accessed as static classes), and to do simple operations such as adding cars to the `Owner`, I should make use of a domain-service, which seems to be, for the simple case, not very API friendly.

Am I right about only having one `CarRepository` instantiated in my system (Singleton), or am I missing something? I'd like to strive for something like

```
public void an_owner_has_cars() throws Exception {
    Owner owner = new Owner(new OwnerId(1));
    CarId carId = new CarId(1);
    Car car = new Car(carId);
    owner.addCar(car);
    Assert.assertEquals(car, owner.getCarOf(carId));
}
```

but that doesn't seem to be possible without injecting a repository into `Owner`, something that seems to be kind of forbidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repository does not represent a collection that belongs to another entity.  The idea is that it represents the *entire* collection of entities.

So in your example `Car` is an entity and probably an aggregate.  So your model is OK on a conceptual level but you need to split the tight coupling between `Car` and `Owner` since `Owner` is most definitely an AR and, in your current model, deleting it would mean all cars belonging to it should be deleted also.

What you are probably after is something like this:

```
public class Owner {
    private IEnumerable<OwnedCar> cars;
}

public class OwnedCar {
    public Guid CarId { get; set; }
}
```

Or, as an alternative to a VO:

```
public class Owner {
    private IEnumerable<Guid> carsOwned;
}
```

So one AR should not reference another AR instance.

Another point is that you probably do not want to inject repositories into entities since that may indicate a bit of a design flaw (somewhat of a code smell).

To get the owned cars into the Owner would be the job of the `OwnerRepository` since it is part of the same aggregate.  There would be no `OwnedCarRepository` since it is a value object.

Comment: I finally got the fact that in DDD there should be *one* repository for each kind of Aggregate Root, and that was my main question. What I find intriguing in all of this, is that this kind of design is very convenient for a database-based system, but is not how a typical application would be written (i.e., as with the code shown in the OP). The examples you gave sure make sense -- provided we are thinking in terms of an application that will have a repository backed up by a database! Shouldn't DDD strive for the design of an infrastructure-free domain? I may be missing something...

Comment: **"So in your example Car is an entity and probably an aggregate. So your model is OK on a conceptual level but you need to split the tight coupling between Car and Owner since Owner is most definitely an AR and, in your current model, deleting it would mean all cars belonging to it should be deleted also."** In my model deleting a car would not be a problem, as there would be a Owner.removeAllCars().

Comment: You are correct in that a repository functions as though it were a collection.  Whether it is backed by a database should not matter.  I wouldn't say that my design makes sense only for a database-backed repository though :) Deleting a car may not be a problem but since an AR is a consistency boundary deleting an owner means all cars belonging to that person are *always* going to be deleted.  If that is the correct behaviour then it is also fine.  This is where domain knowledge is important.

Answer (score 1):

100% for sure, you don't have to make a singleton CarRepository unless you're working in a legacy system which doesn't use any dependency inejction mechanism.

If you find you need to inject CarRepository to Owner to retrieve cars belong to a specific owner, maybe it's a hint that you should re-model there relationship like:

```
public class Owner {

}

public class Car {
    private Owner owner;
}
```

And use CareRepository to achieve your goal:

```
public interface CarRepository {
    List<Car> findBy(String onwer);
}
```

And just a speculation, the static part maybe refer to DomainEvents, like:

```
public class Owner {

    public long quantityOfCarsOwned() {
        return DomainEvents.raise(new SumCarsEvent(this));//static 
    }
}

public class SumCarsEventHandler {
     private CarRepository carRepository;//inject this, SumCarsEventHandler should be a statless bean managed by container like spring

     public long handle(SumCarsEvent event) {
         return carRepository.countBy(event.getOwner());
     }

}
```

In very simple case, it's just too complicated I think.